# IntelliJ - Corrupted Workspace

Tags: intellij-idea

My machine crashed and corrupted my .workspace file in IntelliJ IDEA> I deleted the .workspace file and restarted IDEA. It restarted but now I've lost my Tomcat config.

When I try to re-add, the Application Server menu is greyed out.

Can anyone tell me how to get my config back, or at least re-add it?

I've tried the Local History method but I don't see any previous history.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the Tomcat app server back under settings and you should be fine.  Once you do that, Tomcat will appear as an app server choice again.

Comment: Can't see; can't help.

Answer (score 0):

I restarted and IntelliJ is now working. I don't know what fixed it because I restarted a few time.